# Boost Websocket - illegal use of type 'void'

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to include and compile a boost 1.77.0 websocket in my application.

```
// File.h
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
```

Boost was installed using vcpkg (:x64-windows). When trying to compile, I get the following error:

```
Error C2182 'executor_': illegal use of type 'void' - E:\Github\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\asio\impl\compose.hpp Line 64
```

Has anyone encountered this problem? Couldn't find anything on this issue.

I am using Visual Studio 16.11.5 (C++17).

Note: the project contains `.cu` files. Could this potentially be the issue? Compiling the headers in a separate solution does not yield any errors.

Relevant part of `compose.hpp`:

```
template <typename Executor, typename = void>
class composed_work_guard
{
public:
typedef typename decay<
    typename prefer_result<Executor,
        execution::outstanding_work_t::tracked_t
    >::type
    >::type executor_type;

composed_work_guard(const Executor& ex)
    : executor_(boost::asio::prefer(ex, execution::outstanding_work.tracked))
{
}

void reset()
{
}

executor_type get_executor() const BOOST_ASIO_NOEXCEPT
{
    return executor_;
}

private:
    executor_type executor_; // line 64
};
```

Comment: It may help to see the code around line 64 of `E:\Github\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\boost\asio\impl\compose.hpp`

Comment: You're quite right. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I managed to fix this issue. I put the boost code into a different translation unit which doesn't get touched by the cuda compiler.